# Sweetner for our 4 month baby boy

Tags: food

My 4 month old will not take baby rice or rusk without sweetner. Can you advise me what sweetner I can give him.

Comment: Have you tried adding fruits or veggies? Apples, Bananas and cooked carrots come to mind...

Comment: How does a 4 month old know that it needs sweetener?  Babies will eat if they're hungry.

Comment: I have no suggestions but I want to remind not to give your child honey as it can be a source for infant botulism. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulism A quote: Honey can contain the organism, and for this reason honey should not be fed to children under 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

This is not uncommon; if you mix the cereal with formula, you can add a bit of pasteurized juice instead of water, or, as suggested above by @Layna, add a bit of either fruit puree or a sweet vegetable (carrots, squash, sweet potato, etc.) to the mix.

You should avoid artificial sweeteners and honey for health reasons, and most doctors would disapprove of adding sugar or other concentrated sweet; the fruit/veggie is a much better option nutritionally.